# Writing a vector to csv in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a vector to a .csv final in c++ but the formatting of the .csv file is wrong.

I am currently doing this:

```
    ofstream myfile(rtn);
    int vsize = returns.size();
    for(int n=0; n<vsize; n++)
     {
     myfile << returns[n] << '\t';
     myfile << "," ;
     }
```

Which works but it writes the vector like this:

a,b,c,d, (All in one row but different columns)

I need the code to write:

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
```

All in one column but on different rows. Does anyone have suggestions on how I would go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: The example output you've shown has no commas, where did you want those to be?  The simple answer is put a `\n` in the right spot rather than `\t`.

Comment: Consider replacing ',' with 'std::endl'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ofstream myfile(rtn);
int vsize = returns.size();
for (int n=0; n<vsize; n++)
{
    myfile << returns[n] << endl;
}
```

This writes an endline character after each character is entered into the file. An alternative would be to use `'\n'` in place of `endl` but `endl` is generally favored because it flushes the buffer after the newline character.

Comment: `but endl is generally favored because it flushes the buffer after the newline character.` generally favored by who? You should only manually flush the buffer if you have a reason too, otherwise leave it up to the implementation.

Answer (score 5):

You can implicitly loop through the vector. Replace **std::cout** with the **std::ofstream** to output to file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("b");
    v.push_back("c");

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));


    return 0;
}
```